# Is it possible to have a riemann integrable function not integrable only at an endpoint?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Is it possible to have $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f \in R[c,b]$ for $c\in (a,b)$ and $f \notin R[a,b]$ ? If so, what kind of function behavior are we talking about here? Clearly it's not continuous and not a step function. I would guess it would have to be something special like

$$f(x) := \frac{\sin(\cos(1/x))}{\sin(\cos(1/x))} \, \, \, \forall x \neq0 \\f(x): = 0 \, \, \, \text{when } x = 0 $$

Where the function is becoming more discontinuous as $x$ gets closer to zero but can still be bounded by 1 for infinitely many nonzero lengthed intervals.

Comment: It just needs to blow up as $c \to a$, like for example $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^{-1}$ on $(0,1]$, $f(0) = 0$ say.

Comment: With those hypotheses, $f\in R[a,b]$ iff $f$ is bounded on $[a,b].$ (
Also:$ \dfrac{\cos(\cos(1/x))}{\cos(\cos(1/x))}?$)

Comment: Your example is essentially a step function with $f(x) =1$ for all $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Wonder why you think it is more and more discontinuous. For Riemann integrability of a  bounded function, it is the number (more accurately the size of the set) of discontinuities which matters rather than the nature of individual discontinuities.

Comment: Yeah, I think I see what you mean now. It would be easier to just use $f(x) := 1/x$ for $x \neq 0$ and define $f$ as a some constant at zero. As a matter of fact I think on my paper I just proved that my original problem is riemann integrable.

Comment: The edited function (involving sine as well as cosine) needs to be defined at the points where $\cos(1/x)=0$ and further after this definition at exceptional points is done it is Riemann integrable because the discontinuities form a set of measure $0$.

Comment: Does measure zero mean countable?